# Carregar conteúdo automaticamente ao chegar ao fim da página

Tags: jquery, pdo, paginação

Quero fazer uma paginação automática tipo a do Facebook, que quando chega ao final da página ela automaticamente carrega outra página com mais postagens. Já pesquisei sobre o assunto e não achei nada que pudesse realmente me ajudar a ponto de eu conseguir.

O código que uso pra listar as postagens é esse:

```
<?php 
  $post = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM postagens")->fetchAll();
if(!$post){
  print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
} 
foreach ($post as $posts){
?>
```

Tentei fazer o que o @abfurlan disse e pelo jeito fiz alguma coisa de errado.

A página `index.php` ficou assim:

```
<?php require_once"../conexao.php"?>

<style>
#conteudo{
width:100px; background:#CCC;
height:200px;
overflow-y:auto;
}
</style>

<script src="JS/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#conteudo").scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
      //requisição ajax para selecionar postagens
      $.ajax({
       url:'postagens.php', //Página PHP que seleciona postagens
       type:'POST', // método post, GET ...
       data: 'limit=5&offset=0', //seus paramêtros
       success: function(data){ // sucesso de retorno executar função
         $('#conteudo').append(data); // adiciona o resultado na div #conteudo
       } // fim success
    }); // fim ajax
  } // fim do if
}); // fim scroll
}); // fim document ready
</script>

<div id="conteudo">
</div>
```

E a página `postagens.php` ficou assim:

```
<?php require_once "../conexao.php" ?>

<?php 
$post = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM postagens LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0")->fetchAll();
if(!$post){
    print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
} 
foreach ($post as $posts){
?>

<?php echo $posts['ID']; echo "<br>"?>

<?php } ?>
```

Não está acontecendo nada...

Comment: Acho que a questão não cai bem em "páginação automática", sugiro mudar o título para "carregar conteúdo conforme scroll" ou algo do gênero

Comment: Veja se este post é útil, creio que é isto que está procurando: [Como carregar conteúdo sob demanda usando jQuery](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/19426/jquery/como-carregar-conteudo-sob-demanda-usando-jquery/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A técnica que você busca chama-se conteúdo sob demanda ou scroll infinito.**

Digamos que você tenha em seu código uma `div` que carrega seu conteúdo

```
<div id="conteudo">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

E essa `div` tem um altura fixa e `overflow-y:scroll`:

```
#conteudo{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Então você implementa um código jQuery, para sempre que o scroll chegar ao fim da `div`, seja feita uma requisição ajax para selecionar mais postagens:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#conteudo").scroll(function() { 
      if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
        //requisição ajax para selecionar postagens
        $.ajax({
           url:'minha_pagina_acesso_banco.php', //Página PHP que seleciona postagens
           type:'POST', // método post, GET ...
           data: 'limit=10&offset=0', //seus paramêtros
           success: function(data){ // sucesso de retorno executar função
             $('#conteudo').append(data); // adiciona o resultado na div #conteudo
           } // fim success
        }); // fim ajax
      } // fim do if
    }); // fim scroll
}); // fim document ready
```

No seu código que seleciona as postagem você pode faz um `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`

```
SELECT * FROM postagens LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 ORDER BY DESC;
```

Em sua página PHP, trate os parâmetros recebidos por ajax para realizar a consulta

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM postagens LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($_POST['limit'],$_POST['offset']));
$post = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!$post){
    print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
} 
foreach ($post as $posts){
    echo $posts['ID']; echo "<br>";
} ?>
```

E conforme o `scroll` você incrementa esses valores na requisição ajax para selecionar mais postagens.

**[Veja aqui um exemplo simples do código jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/9nZPG/)**

Comment: tentei fazer o que voce disse e novamente nao consegui.

Comment: @ivanveloso edite a pergunta para adicionar os códigos, assim fica mais fácil de entender

Comment: Pergunta editada

Comment: @ivanveloso editei a resposta, você precisa selecionar dinamicamente as postagens, no seu caso você esta selecionando todas as postagens de uma vez.

Comment: deu esse erro /// Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\calient\jazz\postagens.php on line 8 ////

Comment: @ivanveloso Esse erro ocorre quando a consulta retorna erro, verifique sua consulta, se os parâmetros estão chegando corretamente do `$_POST`.

Comment: O problema é que eu sou uma tristeza com php e jquery então em 50% dos casos, mesmo que seja um erro bobo eu ainda não consigo identificar o problema

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15141/discussion-between-abfurlan-and-ivan-veloso).

Comment: É possível passar os dados para a página ou o php terá que imprimir com html/css obrigatoriamente?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {

        var bottomDiv = $('#div-alvo').height() + $('#div-alvo').offset().top;
        var bottomWindow = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());

        if (bottomWindow > bottomDiv ) {

            //Requisição


        } // fim do if
    }); // fim scroll
});
```

bottomDiv é a posição em pixels de onde a div alvo termina.
bottomWindow é o inferior da tela do usuário.

Quando o inferior da tela do usuário ultrapassar o inferior da div alvo, uma nova requisição deve ser feita.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

10

document.getElementById("bcen").style.align = "center"; // Center
document.getElementById("bcen").style.width =
"300px"; //Size
document.getElementById("bcen").style.align = "center"; // Center
document.getElementById("bcen").style.height =
"200px"; //Size