# Reexibir conteúdo quando usuário rolar tela para baixo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estava precisando carregar conteúdo sob demanda com jquery, mas resolvi o problema com [esta postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21588/carregar-conte%C3%BAdo-automaticamente-ao-chegar-ao-fim-da-p%C3%A1gina). Mas agora o que estou precisando é fazer o contrário... quando carregar o novo conteúdo, o conteúdo que estava sendo exibido precisa ser retirado para que a página não fique tão sobrecarregada... o que ocorre é que não sei como fazer para que quando o usuário decida voltar, o script identifique isso e carregue novamente o conteúdo anterior! Como posso identificar que o usuário está voltando o conteúdo para que eu consiga recarregá-lo?

Comment: Acho legal vc ir carregando conteúdo à medida que vai descendo a tela, tipo no Facebook. Mas analise: fazer o contrário não seria muito interessante, vai lotar o servidor de requisições. Vc não quer "sobrecarregar" a página mas quer sobrecarregar o server? Não faz mt sentido, pelo menos pra mim. O que foi carregado na página "já era", não deve ser puxado de novo, e isso não sobrecarrega a página, como supõe. Recomendo repensar se é isso mesmo que queres.

Comment: Olá, sveen, quanto a carregar o conteúdo de acordo com o rolamento da tela, é isso mesmo que tenho feito. o problema é o contrário. não está sobrecarregando o server, já que os dados que preciso são recuperados na inicialização somente com uma requisição. a partir de então fica salvo num array que posso manipular livremente. na verdade está sobrecarregando a navegação, mais especificamente para leitores de telas para deficientes visuais (Talk Back do android). então depois de uns 20000, 30000 caracteres, o leitor começa a dar uma pausa muito grande de um elemento para o outro.